# parameter set to None when inheriting from BigQueryOperator in Apache Airflow 1.10.2

Tags: python-2.7, airflow

I'm upgrading to Airflow 1.10.2 from 1.9.0, in python 2.7, and I'm having troubles with `airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py`, more precisely with the deprecation of `bql` parameter in favor of `sql`

I have a class hierarchy based on `BigQueryOperator`

```
BigQueryToPartitionTableOperator -> BigQueryFromExternalSqlOperator -> BigQueryOperator
```

```py
class BigQueryFromExternalSqlOperator(BigQueryOperator):
    template_fields = BigQueryOperator.template_fields + ('get_sql_kwargs',)

    def __init__(self, get_sql_func, get_sql_kwargs={}, *args, **kwargs):

        super(BigQueryFromExternalSqlOperator, self).__init__(bql='',  #/!\ problematic parameter
                                                              *args,
                                                              **kwargs)
        self.get_sql_func = get_sql_func
        self.get_sql_kwargs = get_sql_kwargs

    def get_sql(self):
        return self.get_sql_func(**self.get_sql_kwargs)

    def pre_execute(self, context):
        self.bql = self.get_sql()


class BigQueryToPartitionTableOperator(BigQueryFromExternalSqlOperator):
    template_fields = ('get_schema_kwargs',) + BigQueryFromExternalSqlOperator.template_fields
    template_ext = ('_.sql',)

    def __init__(self, get_schema_func, get_schema_kwargs={}, *args, **kwargs):

        super(BigQueryToPartitionTableOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.hook = BigQueryTableHook(bigquery_conn_id=self.bigquery_conn_id,
                                      delegate_to=self.delegate_to)
        self.get_schema_func = get_schema_func
        self.get_schema_kwargs = get_schema_kwargs
        self.schema = None
```

One of my DAGs is using `BigQueryToPartitionTableOperator`.
When I do an `airflow list_dags` to get the parseable ones, here is what I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 374, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/processing/dags/learning/clustering_activity/dag.py", line 37, in <module>
    "period": Variable.get("activity_clustering.period")
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/processing/common/dags/inference_dag.py", line 215, in __enter__
    dataset_partitioned=self.dataset,
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/processing/common/operators/big_query_operator.py", line 79, in __init__
    super(BigQueryShardedToPartitionedOperator, self).__init__(bql=None, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/decorators.py", line 97, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py", line 176, in __init__
    'argument: `sql`'.format(self.task_id))
TypeError: inferred_to_partitioned missing 1 required positional argument: `sql`
```

When I check the code for [BigQueryOpertor](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.2/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py#L174), most relevant part in `__init__` below, `self.sql` is tested

```py
@apply_defaults
def __init__(sql=None, bql=None, ...):
    ...
    self.sql = sql if sql else bql # /!\ how self.sql is set
    ...
    # TODO remove `bql` in Airflow 2.0
        if self.bql:
            import warnings
            warnings.warn('Deprecated parameter `bql` used in Task id: {}. '
                          'Use `sql` parameter instead to pass the sql to be '
                          'executed. `bql` parameter is deprecated and '
                          'will be removed in a future version of '
                          'Airflow.'.format(self.task_id),
                          category=DeprecationWarning)

        if self.sql is None:
            raise TypeError('{} missing 1 required positional '
'argument: `sql`'.format(self.task_id))
```

although I put a default value for `bql`, `bql=''` in `BigQueryFromExternalSqlOperator` I'm still getting the same exception as above.

I don't know if this has something to do with inheritance and default args in python when instantiating objects.

Or maybe the `apply_defaults` decorator in [decorators.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.2/airflow/utils/decorators.py) is altering the parameters passed to `BigQueryOperator`'s `__init__` function.

**EDIT 1:**
here is how I call the operator

```
class myDAG(DAG):

...
    def __enter__():
        ...
        # Save the input dataset in version-suffixed table in BQ
        extract_dataset = BigQueryToPartitionTableOperator(task_id='extract_dataset',
                                                           get_sql_func=self.get_sql,
                                                           get_schema_func=self.get_schema,
                                                           get_sql_kwargs=self.get_extract_dataset_sql_kwargs,
                                                           get_schema_kwargs=self.get_extracted_table_schema_kwargs,
                                                           destination_dataset_table='{}.{}'.format(
                                                               self.dataset,
                                                               self.extracted_table),
                                                           write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                                                           use_legacy_sql=False,
                                                           bigquery_conn_id=self.gcp_conn_id)
```

Comment: Hi, can you show how do you use the BigQueryToPartitionTableOperator in your DAG ? You can replace any sensitive information by 'xxxx'.

Comment: @bartosz25 I added the DAG code section that uses BigQueryToPartitionTableOperator

Comment: I'm wondering if you managed to debug the problem? Especially that your stack trace has a mention of `"super(BigQueryShardedToPartitionedOperator, self).__init__(bql=None, *args, **kwargs)`" which is not listed in your initial class hierarchy based on `BigQueryOperator`.

Comment: @bartosz25 Thanks for you help. I finally found the issue. I missread the stacktrace. I changed the right line: `super(BigQueryShardedToPartitionedOperator, self).__init__(bql='', *args, **kwargs)` not the one in `super(BigQueryFromExternalSqlOperator, self).__init__(bql='', *args, **kwargs)` as shown above. Thanks again, your previous comment really helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for adding the snippet. If I understand that correctly, you aren't passing the `sql` argument about what is complaining the error message `TypeError: inferred_to_partitioned missing 1 required positional argument: sql`

Try to fix it that way:

- pass `sql` attribute to your parent BigQueryOpertor which is not empty, just for debugging

```
class BigQueryFromExternalSqlOperator(BigQueryOperator):
    template_fields = BigQueryOperator.template_fields + ('get_sql_kwargs',)

    def __init__(self, get_sql_func, get_sql_kwargs={}, *args, **kwargs):

        super(BigQueryFromExternalSqlOperator, self).__init__(sql = 'SELECT ....',
                                                              *args,
                                                              **kwargs)
```

- if after that the 'missing 1 required position argument: sql' error disappeared, find a way to pass your query to the `BigQueryOperator` sql argument or, if you don't want to delegate the query execution to it, override the method that is executing it. But if you don't need `BigQueryOperator` execution, it will be simpler to get rid of this parent.

Comment: `bql = ''` in `BigQueryFromExternalSqlOperator` solved the issue

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up ! :)